# Fire double tap command to android device using adb

Tags: android, adb

I have been trying to send a command to my device to double tap on the screen. 
I tried to send this

```
adb shell input tap 600 1000
adb shell input tap 600 1000
```

However, it does not result into a doubletap. 
Anyone willing to help me out?

Answer (score 3):

This has worked for me pretty reliably until android 10; however, it no longer works on android 11 :(

I figured out a way to do it like this:

```
input tap <x> <y>&
sleep 0.1
input tap <x> <y>
```

as in

> adb shell "input tap 520 1150& sleep 0.1; input tap 520 1150"

When digging around android 11 it seems that input command spawns up a JVM that is very slow, and it slowed down enough on android 11 to about 0.5 seconds, so the system does not recognize it as a double tap.

You can speed up the taps (or any user input) by including it in the same adb shell command. Previously I did this:

> adb shell "input tap 520 1150; input tap 520 1150"

This will be easier on your system memory (as only one input command is executing at once) and may work pre android 11, but the one with & and explicit sleep between the two taps is what I switched to now.